# jQuery made up attribute not getting value

Tags: jquery, custom-attributes, attr

Hey all i am trying to get the value of the clicked custom radio button that ive made.

Here is the js for the button:

```
$("#df-opt0,#df-opt1,#df-opt2,#df-opt3,#df-opt4").click(function (input) {
    $('#df-opt0').css("background-image", "url(img/radiobutton-OFF.png)");
    $('#df-opt1').css("background-image", "url(img/radiobutton-OFF.png)");
    $('#df-opt2').css("background-image", "url(img/radiobutton-OFF.png)");
    $('#df-opt3').css("background-image", "url(img/radiobutton-OFF.png)");
    $('#df-opt4').css("background-image", "url(img/radiobutton-OFF.png)");
    //alert($(this).attr('id'));
    $('#' + $(this).attr('id')).css("background-image", "url(img/radiobutton-ON.png)");
    //globalRadioSelected = $(this).attr('id');

    fValue =  $(input).attr("store-id");
    alert('the ID :'+fValue);
});
```

And this is the HTML:

```
<div id="df-opt0" store-id="100"></div>
<div id="df-opt1" store-id="200"></div>
<div id="df-opt2" store-id="300"></div>
<div id="df-opt3" store-id="400"></div>
<div id="df-opt4" store-id="500"></div>
<div id="df-opt4txt" store-id="600">
    <input type="text" id="df-opt4txt-txt" style="width: 130px;" class="formBoxes">
</div>
```

What i get when i click on any of them is: **the ID : undefined**

What am i missing?

Comment: It might be worth using the `data-` attribute rather than just a custom attribute. e.g. using `data-store-id`. If you read this SO post you will see why http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7261619/jquery-data-vs-attr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use "this" ala:

```
fValue =  $(this).attr("store-id");
```

Answer (score 1):

Do `fValue =  $(this).attr("store-id");` not `fValue =  $(input).attr("store-id");`.

The argument passed to your click handler function is the click event itself which obviously does not have a `store-id` attribute.

The `this` object will be the same as `input.target` (the target DOM element for the click event) in this situation.